# How to make Servers and Clients connect non-locally?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

So I have created a very simple client and server program on Python which runs fine with both being on my local machine.

But say if the Client was on another machine and server on another. How would I modify or what do I implement in my code to connect server and client together not being on the same machine ?

smallserver.py

```
import socket as mysoc
import threading
import time
import random

# ts server task

def server():

# creating ts server socket

    global ts

    try:
        ts=mysoc.socket(mysoc.AF_INET, mysoc.SOCK_STREAM)
        print("ts Server socket created")
    except mysoc.error as err:
        print('{} \n'.format("socket open error ",err))

# bind and listen to client

    server_binding=('',50006)
    ts.bind(server_binding)

    ts.listen(1)

# accept client socket connection request


    csockid,addr = ts.accept()
    print ("[ts Server]: Got a connection request from a client at", addr)

# send a intro message to the client.

    msg = "Connected to ts.py server"
    csockid.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))

# receiving and decoding message sent from client

    data_from_client = (csockid.recv(1024))
    word = data_from_client.decode('utf-8').lower()
    print('[Client]: ' + word)

# close the ts server socket

    ts.close()
    exit()

# threading

t1 = threading.Thread(name='server', target = server)
t1.start()
time.sleep(random.random()*5)

exit()

# END OF TS SERVER PROGRAM
```

smallclient.py

```
import threading
import socket as mysoc

# client

def client():

# creating 2 different sockets

    global cs

    try:
        cs = mysoc.socket(mysoc.AF_INET, mysoc.SOCK_STREAM)
        print("[Client]: 1st client socket created")
    except mysoc.error as err:
        print('{} \n'.format("socket open error ", err))

# defining ports of both potential servers

    rsListenport = 50006
    sa_sameas_myaddr = mysoc.gethostbyname(mysoc.gethostname())

# connect to the rs server on local machine

    print("[Client] = Connecting to rs server.....")

    server_binding = (sa_sameas_myaddr, rsListenport)
    cs.connect(server_binding)

# printing acknowledgement message from rs server

    data_from_server = cs.recv(100)
    print("[rs Server]: ", data_from_server.decode('utf-8'))

# closing both client sockets

    cs.close()
    exit()

# threading

t2 = threading.Thread(name='client', target=client)
t2.start()

exit()

# END OF CLIENT PROGRAM
```

Comment: you would need to bind to `'0.0.0.0'` and have the client target the public ip of the server ... the server also has to expose the target port to the internet (you can get the public ip from whatismyip.org or any number of other places)